# JavaScript - Background switch between green and white with button

Tags: javascript

I wanted to ask how I do it, when you click the button, the background turns green, it goes back again with the same button, so that it then becomes white again.

```
spanTwo.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      liItem.style.background = 'rgb(24, 189,24';
      liItem.style.color = 'white';
```

Comment: Toggle a class for the button on click. With the class you can change the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There's too many ways to do that you can try one of those

1. Check the element background and apply your style

```
spanTwo.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      if(getComputedStyle(liItem, null).backgroundColor !== "rgb(24, 189, 24)") {
           liItem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(24, 189, 24)';
           liItem.style.color = 'white';
      } else {
           liItem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
           liItem.style.color = 'white';
      }
})
```

2. Toggle class

```
.liItem {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.green {
    background: rgb(24, 189, 24);
    color: #fff;
}
```

```
spanTwo.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      liItem.classList.toggle("green")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution 1:

Add *onlick* event to the `button`, and check, if the `target.backgroundColor` = `white`? Then change to `green`. Else? change to `white`. This will toggle between the two values.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var target = document.body;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  target.style.backgroundColor == 'green' ? target.style.backgroundColor = 'white' : target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
})
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Change</button>
```

#### Solution 2:

**Toggle** between a class and a manually added `property: value` to override it.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var target = document.body;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  target.classList.toggle('bg_green')
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.bg_green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Change</button>
```

#### Solution 3:

**Toggle** two classes, one for each `value (color)`.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var target = document.body;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  target.className == 'bg_green' ? target.className = 'bg_white' : target.className = 'bg_green';
})
```

```css
.bg_green {
    background-color: green;
}

.bg_white {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Change</button>
```

##### Extra (Longer) Solution:

Check if `target` contains one of these `class names` (green in the example), if yes remove it and add the other (white). And it'll repeat it self (toggle).

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var target = document.body;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(target.classList.contains('bg_green')){
    target.classList.add('bg_white');
    target.classList.remove('bg_green');
  } else {
    target.classList.add('bg_green');
    target.classList.remove('bg_white');
  }
})
```

```css
.bg_green {
    background-color: green;
}

.bg_white {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Change</button>
```

##### Note:

The **JavaScript** `classList` property is recommended over `className`, since it allows us to *add*, *delete* and *toggle* a `Class List`, in case the `target` contains more than *1* `class name`.

**MDN - Element.classList:**

> The Element.classList is a read-only property that
> returns a live DOMTokenList collection of the class attributes of the
> element. This can then be used *to manipulate the class list*.

More details:
[MDN - Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) 
[MDN - Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(24, 189,24);
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>
```